# How to speed up sound and video and modify the pitch?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to increase speed on both the sound and the video, while adding pitch to the audio alone.

I have those two ffmpeg commands, but I don't know how to make them work together.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.94*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=1.06[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:a "atempo=1.06,asetrate=44100*1.25" output.mkv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.94*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=1.06,asetrate=44100*1.25[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv
```

Although I assume you want to reset the audio sample rate from 55125 back to 44100:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.94*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=1.06,asetrate=44100*1.25,aformat=sample_rates=44100[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv
```

Alternatively, just add `-ar 44100` output option to the first example.